# Extracting only the body links on reddit using C# Regex.matches

Tags: c#, html, regex

Currently I am only getting the links in the header, i cannot receive the links that are apart of the updated body.

```
private static void HTMLtoLinkList(string HTMLTEXT)
{
    var LParser = new Regex(@"\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    foreach (Match m in LParser.Matches(HTMLTEXT))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m);
        Console.ReadLine();            
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include samples of text it will match and samples you want it to match?

Comment: Try parsing the html instead with https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ . Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4665 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/4665